# Application dedicated Android Device is it possible?

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, dedicated

I have been tasked with sourcing an off the shelf touch pad device that can be used as a dedicated industrial instrument controller.

Is it possible to run a dedicated application and prevent user access to all other functions/applications within Android.

Also is it possible write your own USB device driver which would allow you to connect an USB serial class device?

Comment: Since android os open source you can use it for whatever you want. Just depends on how much work you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Like already stated Android is open source. You can take the sources and recode them to your desire so that the device behaves like you want.

In the end the default android launcher and all other applications are all just standard Java applications (mainly). You can recode it so that instead of loading the launcher app it loads up your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this OS to make your own custom gadgets same as you can use linux in embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

Its open source so you can go down into the OS code and disable what you like. So i would say it is indeed possible. Windows does also do windows embedded like windows CE/WM range, these have touch screens and come in rugged form factors too, M3,PSION and others.

You can recode the OS visual display, i.e. HTC sense on all their phones. So you could recode it to show nothing.

As to the driver, well a driver is a driver this will also be possible.